# Intermittent error 'This node is not ready to answer queries yet' in Azure Data Explorer (kusto)

Tags: azure-data-explorer

On a 5 node V2 kusto cluster, there are intermittent errors while running both commands and queries:

"This node is not ready to answer queries yet. This is usually a temporary error that occurs while the service is becoming online. Admin service state is: Role=BecomingPrimary"

How to avoid this error altogether, and how long should one wait before retrying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error suggests that the database admin node is transitioning - it's a transient state that could occur periodically.

If the issue persists, it could either be a result of over-usage, leading to significant load on the admin node, or a different issue.

If you need assistance with troubleshooting, I would recommend that you open a support request via the Azure portal.

Comment: I have observed this error mostly when ~10 long running queries are executing concurrently on the cluster. Would passing the queryconsistency client request property as weakconsistency be a good idea to solve this issue by reducing load on admin node, if I don't need "read-my-changes" guarantee?

Comment: That is certainly an option, assuming you've already optimized your schema and queries based on documented best practices. More options can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/high-concurrency